# Rails: Ensure phone number is unique checking several columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two columns, `phone_1` and `phone_2`.

I want to ensure that once a phone number is entered in any of these fields, the same number cannot be saved on the same record or on any other future record in either one of these two columns.

How to achieve this on a database level and on a model level?

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :normalize_phones

  validates :phone_1, phone: true, allow_blank: true
  validates :phone_2, phone: true, allow_blank: true
    
  private

  # https://justincypret.com/blog/validating-normalizing-and-formatting-phone-numbers-in-rails
  def normalize_phones
    self.phone_1 = normalize_phone(self.phone_1)
    self.phone_2 = normalize_phone(self.phone_2)
  end   

  # https://justincypret.com/blog/validating-normalizing-and-formatting-phone-numbers-in-rails
  def normalize_phone(phone)
    self.phone_1 = Phonelib.parse(phone_1).full_e164.presence
    self.phone_2 = Phonelib.parse(phone_2).full_e164.presence
  end   
end
```

Comment: While the validation itself should not be all the difficult (e.g. `Brand.where.not(id:self.id).where(phone_1: [phone_1,phone_2]).or(Brand.where(phone_2: [phone_1,phone_2])).exists?`) are you sure this is a good idea? I personally have worked for more than 1 company that had/supported multiple brands and not all of them had unique phone numbers (you were just routed differently in the phone system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just go a completly different direction:

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :phone_numbers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers
end

# rails g model phone_number number:uniq description
class PhoneNumber < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :brand
  validates :number,
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: true
end
```

This ensures the uniqueness both on the db and application level while allowing you to attach any arbitrary number of phone numbers.